# Activating NSLayoutConstraints Causes Xcode to Freeze

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am activating many `NSLayoutConstraints` in a single array. At a certain point (about 9 or 10 constraints), Xcode stops highlighting syntax, and won't build the project. This is very repeatable: removing the constraints from the array instantly fixes the problem.

I have tried quitting Xcode, cleaning the project, restarting the computer. Nothing fixes it. Is this a known issue, or is there any obvious fix?

I can confirm that the constraints do not interfere with each other: if you split them up into two different `activateConstraint` methods, it works fine.

To be clear, the code is simply:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: attribute: relatedBy: toItem: attribute: .Width, multiplier: constant:),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: attribute: relatedBy: toItem: attribute: .Width, multiplier: constant:),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: attribute: relatedBy: toItem: attribute: .Width, multiplier: constant:),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: attribute: relatedBy: toItem: attribute: .Width, multiplier: constant:),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: attribute: relatedBy: toItem: attribute: .Width, multiplier: constant:),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: attribute: relatedBy: toItem: attribute: .Width, multiplier: constant:),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: attribute: relatedBy: toItem: attribute: .Width, multiplier: constant:),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: attribute: relatedBy: toItem: attribute: .Width, multiplier: constant:),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: attribute: relatedBy: toItem: attribute: .Width, multiplier: constant:),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: attribute: relatedBy: toItem: attribute: .Width, multiplier: constant:),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: attribute: relatedBy: toItem: attribute: .Width, multiplier: constant:),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: attribute: relatedBy: toItem: attribute: .Width, multiplier: constant:),
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: attribute: relatedBy: toItem: attribute: .Width, multiplier: constant:)
    ])
```